# Python Parse JSON objects in Different Way

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonparser

I'm working on a python project In which we are getting some inputs from the user.
We are working on microservice deployments actually. Where user needs to provide the following things:

1): User will provide a GitHub repo which will include all of his microservices he wants to deploy inside a specific directory.
For example, we have a directory structure in GitHub repo  like this:
`mysvcs
 |----nodeservice
 |----pyservice`

2): User will provide a JSON object in which he will mention the URL for this repo and some other information for these microservices, like this:

```
{
  "repo_url": "https://github.com/arycloud/mysvcs.git",

  "services":[
        {
        "name": "pyservice",
        "routing": {
          "path": "/",
          "service": "pyservice",
          "port": "5000"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "nodeservice",
        "routing": {
          "path": "/",
          "service": "nodeservice",
          "port": "8080"
        }
      }
        ]
}
```

Then we are reading all the services from GitHub repo and using their directories to read the source code., and along with that, we are parsing the JSON object to get some information regarding these services.

We are reading the repo like this:

```
tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
saved_unmask = os.umask(0o077)
out_dir = os.path.join(tempdir)
Repo.clone_from(data['repo_url'], out_dir)
list_dir = os.listdir(out_dir)
print(list_dir)
services = []
for svc in range(0, len(data['services'])):
    services.append(list_dir[svc])

print(services)
```

According to our example above, it will return:

```
['nodesvc', 'pyservice']
```

But when we are reading the JSON object there user have mentioned the services in different order instead of alphabetically, so when we are the loop through the services using the above array we are trying to use the same index for JSON object services and the list of directories after cloning the GitHub repo but due to different orders it interchange the data.

Here's a sample code:

```
def my_deployment(data):
    # data is JSON object
    # Clone github repo and grab Dockerfiles
    tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    saved_unmask = os.umask(0o077)
    out_dir = os.path.join(tempdir)
    Repo.clone_from(data['repo_url'], out_dir)
    list_dir = os.listdir(out_dir)
    print(list_dir)
    services = []
    for svc in range(0, len(data['services'])):
        services.append(list_dir[svc])
    print(services)
    for service in range(len(services)):
        # Here i need to use the data from JSON object for current service 
        data['services'][service]['routing']['port']
        # Here it's using the data of **pyservice** instead of **nodeservice** and vice versa.
```

> **Important**:  Ther order of services in GitHub is `['nodeservices', 'nodeservices']` but in the JSON object user can mention his services in a different order like `pyservices, nodeservices`. So when we are looping through how can we sync the order of both of these sources? This is the main issue.

I have tried it by changing the structure of my JSON object in this way:

```
"services":[
    "pyservice": {
      "routing": {
        "path": "/",
        "service": "pyservice",
        "port": "5000"
      }
    },
    "nodeservice": {
      "routing": {
        "path": "/node",
        "service": "nodeservice",
        "port": "8080"
      }
    }
]
```

But it says `syntax is not correct`.
How can I overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to change the `[]` to `{}` in the json

Comment: Hi @shadowtalker, it' s JSON array of objects.

Comment: If you run your code in  [JSON validator](https://jsonformatter.org/) you'll see it's not valid.

Comment: Hi @VilleKoo, Which one? I have posted 2 version of JSON object, first, one valid and second one is not as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AbdulRehman The bottom one

Comment: Yup, it is, I have mentioned, I was just showing that if we can overcome this issue by changing our JSON object.

Comment: Why can't Services be an object instead of array? From what I see, you are just iterating through the Services array and then grabbing the name of the service. So  instead, if you keep Services a key-value map, it will allow you to iterate as well as will save you from the issues of index number and order. Something like this:
"services" : {
    "pyservice": {"something":"something},
    "nodeservice" : {"x" : "y"}
}
You can iterate over all key value pairs of services as well!

Comment: Actually, we are also getting the no of services the user wants to host from the length of this array, without this array how can we get the number of services user will provide?

Comment: @AbdulRehman count the number of keys? this is trivial in Javascript and Python. You can't name elements of an array.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the JSON is not valid, is that you can't have name value pairs in a JSON array. [This](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvjsn/json-data-types.html) page tells you an array can be:

> A comma-delimited list of unnamed values, either simple or complex, enclosed in brackets

Is the below JSON any use?

```
{
  "repo_url": "https://github.com/arycloud/mysvcs.git",

  "services":[
    {
      "pyservice": {
        "routing": {
          "path": "/",
          "service": "pyservice",
          "port": "5000"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "nodeservice": {
        "routing": {
          "path": "/node",
          "service": "nodeservice",
          "port": "8080"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want `services` sorted alphabetically, you can do the following:

```
services = data["services"]

b = {}
for node in services:
  b.update(dict(node))

alphabetical_list = sorted(b)
```

Note:

This gives you a list `['nodeservice', 'pyservice']` which you can then use to get the object in `b`.

Comment: Hi @NeRa, but how can we sync the order of this JSON array to the order of directories list `['nodesvc', 'pyservice']` from Github repo? That's the main issue. Because even in this way we need to use the index to loop through the services array.

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to do it alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking too complicated.

```
for svc in data['services']:
    print(svc['name'], svc['routing']['port'])
```

Done.

General observation: You seem to cling to loop indexes. Don't. It's a good thing that Python loops have no indexes.

Whenever you are tempted to write

```
for thing in range(len(some_list)):
```

**stop**, and write

```
for thing in some_list:
```

instead.

Comment: Hi @Tomalak, the issue is the order of services in the two places are different. Can we re-order the services array in JSON object into alphabetically? it will be matched with the order in GitHub repo.

Comment: Which two places? Don't build a `svc_list` variable in the first place and you're good. `data['services']` is your service list.

Comment: One place is Github repo and the other is JSON object array.

Comment: I don't get it. You have a `svc` object with all the relevant information. Name, port, whatever. The service `name` exactly matches a directory name in the repo. What *else* do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Here an approach we can use to overcome this order-sync issue:

First, the order of directories in GitHub repo is by default alphabetically, so if we sort the order for the array of services in JSON objects we will be able to get the same index for both sources. Even to make sure we can sort both of these sources alphabetically.

Here's the code:
First sort the services array of JSON object as:

```
data['services'] = sorted(data["services"], key=lambda d: d["name"])
```

By considering the example in the question, it will give us:

```
services = [
   {"nodeservice": {
     "A": "B"
     }
   },
   {"pyservice":{
     "X": "Y"
    }
   }
]
```

Then we will sort the list of directories from GitHub repo like this:

```
Repo.clone_from(data['repo_url'], out_dir)
list_dir = os.listdir(out_dir)
print(list_dir)
services = []
for svc in range(0, len(data['services'])):
    services.append(list_dir[svc])

services.sort()
print(services)
```

It will give us: **`['nodeservice', 'pyservice']`** according to the example above in the question.

So, In both cases we have the `nodeservice` first the `pyservice`, mean the same order.